# LINQ greater than date query (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, linq

Goal:

1. order records by 'start_date'
2. select first record
3. get the id of the record returned

When I attempt to **order all events by 'start_date'** and **select the first record returned** ...

code examples:

```
        var aa = (from a in db.Events
              where a.start_date >= System.DateTime.Now.Date
              orderby a.start_date ascending
              select a).FirstOrDefault();

        Response.Write(aa.id.ToString());
```

...I throw an "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*" error.

Comment: Is by any chance the start_date field nullable? In which line exactly are you getting the exception?

Comment: That probably means there weren't any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault()` returns null if your `IQuerable` returns an empty collection - that's why you get that exception. Looks like there is no event that has a start date larger than `DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: Sirs, you are correct. I've been looking at this for over 3 hours and been programming long enough to where this is embarrassing. I confirmed that the 1 record I was looking to return had a date of 2/13/2002. I've corrected this to 2012. However now I'm returning another error. I'll troubleshoot that and if I can't get it I'll post a new question. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Is db==null?

If there are no results, FirstOrDefault() will also return null!